# How to copy an anchor tag along with its hyperlink into excel using selenium in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want copy an anchor tag along with its value and hyperlink into excel.
I have written the code for transferring data into excel.  Don't worry.
All I need to know how to copy a hyperlink into excel. I have tried a lot where I can only copy the value of anchor tag but not the link

I want to fetch the hyperlink named "ATPase activity"

[image]

and copy to excel sheet. When I manually copy it to the excel, I am able to copy the "ATPase activity" along with its link which turned into blue color and underlined.

[image]

BUt the same i am unable to do with selenium code.

The inspect element for the hyperlink "ATPase activity"

[image]

I have tried using

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="noNumbering biological_process"]/li/a')[0].text
```

but it is giving only the value "ATPase activity" but not its link. and I tried

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="noNumberingbiological_process"]/li/a')[0].get_attribute('href')
```

but this gives the link `https://www.ebi.ac.uk/QuickGO/term/GO:0042026` as output.

I need a hyperlink whose display is "ATPase activity" and its link `https://www.ebi.ac.uk/QuickGO/term/GO:0042026` same as shown in the website.

Answer (score 1):

Basically that is a href in a tag. Selenium gives a feature where we can get the tag attribute using `get_attribute`, below is the sample code for that :

```
link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="noNumbering biological_process"]/li/a')
print(link.get_attribute('href'))
print(link.text)
```

Comment: Hi there I have tried the above one too.. It gives me the hyperlink but not the value for the above code you have given, i have tried it the output is "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/QuickGO/term/GO:0042026" I need a hyperlink with value as "ATPase activity" and its link being  "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/QuickGO/term/GO:0042026" to excel .

Comment: Just modified the code little bit, you can print them like this.